# Leaflet.js wrap LatLng positions of line to nearest line

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, latitude-longitude

I want to have the user click two positions and then draw a line between them. This is totally functional and easy. And it also works if the click is outside the -180;180 range.

```
createPolyLine(outside2, userLocation);

//draw polyline
function createPolyLine(loc1, loc2) {

var latlongs = [loc1, loc2];

console.log(loc1);

var polyline = new L.Polyline(latlongs, {
    color: 'white',
    opacity: 1,
    weight: 1,
    clickable: false
}).addTo(map);

}
```

Now If a user clicks say on longitude of -600 I want to have it automatically wrap into the -180;180 area but only if its the closest path. If its closer to keep the click in the -360:-180 area then it should wrap into the -360;-180 area. Same for the other side in positive direction ofcourse.
Example image of what i mean:

[Example of when its closer to use -360;-180 region and not wrap it into -180;180](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CEtt.png)

[Example of when its closer to use -180;180 and it would be wrong now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzGKH.png)

[Based on second example but correctly wrapped now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ojf5.png)

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this auto wrap into either -360;-180 / -180;180 / 180;360 depending on where the closest line between two points would be?

Comment: It seems like you need to find the minimum of the absolute value of the difference modulo 360. I'm not sure that is always true but should work in all practical instances not halfway around the world.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the response of Corey Alix I came up with a solution which feels kinda dirty but it works for all the test cases I tried against. In my scenario one point is always in -180;180 range.

```
// a is always in -180;180
function getPositions(a, b) {
    
  b.lng %= 360;
  
  let abs = Math.abs(a.lng - b.lng);
  let absWrap = Math.abs(a.lng - b.wrap().lng);
  
  if(absWrap < abs) {
    b = b.wrap();
    abs = absWrap;
  }
  
  let left = new L.LatLng(b.lat, b.lng - 360);
  let right = new L.LatLng(b.lat, b.lng + 360);
  
  let leftAbs = Math.abs(a.lng - left.lng);
  
    if(leftAbs < abs) {
    b = left;
    abs = leftAbs;
  }
  
  if(Math.abs(a.lng - right.lng) < abs) {
    b = right;
  }
  
  return [a, b];
  
}

//draw polyline
function createPolyLine(loc1, loc2) {
    
    var latlongs = getPositions(loc2, loc1);
    
    polyline = new L.Polyline(latlongs, {
        color: 'white',
        opacity: 1,
        weight: 1,
        clickable: false
    }).addTo(map);

}
```